# How do I install prerequisites for TeamCity to connect to Team Foundation Server Version Control?

Tags: tfs, version-control, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've installed the prerequisite (Team Explorer 2013) to the best of my knowledge, but when I try to set up a VCS root to connect to our TFS Version Control server, I continue to get this error message:

> "No TFS assemblies were found on the system. Please make sure you have
>   Microsoft Team Explorer installed. Supported versions: 2015 2013 2012
>   2010 2008 2005"

The `Team Explorer` I downloaded from Microsoft just seemed to be a plugin for Visual Studio, which doesn't make much sense as a `server-side component`. Anyway, I configured a connection to our TFS box within Team Explorer/Visual Studio on my TeamCity server.

So I have two questions that seem to be undocumented by JetBrains:

1. What does it mean to set up and configure Team Explorer?  How can I validate that I have set up and configured Team Explorer on my TeamCity server correctly?
2. How does TeamCity know how to find the Team Explorer assemblies?  Is there some sort of configuration I am supposed to do?  Where is this documented?

I guess I'm looking for a true step-by-step set of instructions that make no assumptions about my understanding of `TFS` or Team Explorer, or any assumptions about what I may have already installed on my `TeamCity box`.

I've read the two articles on the JetBrains site regarding how to set this up, and they don't cover actually installing and configuring the prerequisites or configuring `TeamCity` to discover the Team Explorer assemblies it needs.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Explorer is the client software that you use to access Visual Studio Team Foundation Server functionality from Visual Studio. You can simply launch Team Explorer on your TeamCity server to create a team project and check in a project, to validate whether it is installed correctly.

I couldn't find any documentation that mentioned how does TeamCity find Team Explorer assemblies. But, based on my understanding, there is no configuration needed to detect Team Explorer. Please make sure your TeamCity server is running under **Windows**.

If the issue that can't find Team Explorer persists, you can install VS Premium instead of Team Explorer.

[Setting up Jetbrains TeamCity for CI with Team Foundation Server](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.jp/2013/11/setting-up-jetbrains-teamcity-for-ci.html):

1. Install Jetbrains TeamCity
2. If you are planning on using IIS or TFS on the same server, configure Jetbrains TeamCity to run on a port other than 80 or 8080
3. Once TeamCity is up and running, you can begin configuring your TeamCity installation for CI Builds.
4. Log into TeamCity with your user name and password
5. Create a new TeamCity Project
6. Create a new build configuration
7. You will now see a series of build configuration settings that you will have to complete presented in a Wizard-style navigation view.
8. Enter General Settings
9. Enter VCS Settings
10. After entering VCS Settings, Create and attach new VCS Root
11. Enter the relevant information for your TFS instance
12. Create a Build Step using Visual Studio as your build runner.  You can create as many build steps as you need and specify the order of the steps (similar to a TFS Build Workflow).
13. For setting up Continuous Integration builds, you will need to specify a Build Trigger.  CI Builds will generally use a VCS Trigger that is triggered on each source control check-in.
14. If you need to pass any parameters to your build, you can configure these in your Build Parameters.
15. That is all!  You can then either run your Builds manually by clicking on the Run button in TeamCity or simply verify that your builds are triggered by the next check-in into TFS.

Comment: I repaired my Team Explorer installation and then restarted the server, and all is well!  Thank you for your help, Cece.